# preference.getKey.equals() returns false

Tags: java, android

I'm using a `PreferenceActivity` and implementing the `onPreferenceChange` method.
I'm checking to see what preference is changed so I can action it, however, the `.equals()` method keeps returning false. I've debugged the app and it shows that both fields are returning the string `student_id`. Am I missing something?
At this point, the change is coming from the `student_id_key` preference change

From `strings.xml`

```
<string name="student_id_key" translatable="false">student_id</string>
```

code in `onPreferenceChange`

```
 if(preference.getKey().equals(preference.getContext().getString(R.string.student_id_key))){
            //do something here, but its returning false
        }
```

Here's a snapshot of the debugger, showing x and y as the two strings
[image]

I've tried using `==` but with the same result
[image]

This is the excerpt of the element from my prefs.xml

```
  <EditTextPreference
    android:capitalize="words"
    android:defaultValue="@string/student_id_default"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:hint="@string/student_id_hint"
    android:key="@string/student_id_key"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:maxLength="9"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_display_name" />
```

Comment: post code that demonstrate your efforts to prove that both values are indeed equal

Comment: try to reverse your `if`, like this `if (preference.getContext().getString(R.string.student_id_key).equals(preference.getKey())) {}` maybe it helps =)

Comment: so why don't you use `x.equals(y)`?

Comment: same result, it evaluates to false - these were added just to debug it,

Comment: what about `x == y`?

Comment: again, no change. see new image

Comment: what about `Arrays.equals(x.getBytes(), y.getBytes())`? If this returns `false` it can only means that this two strings just **look** the same, but they are not the same.

Comment: added prefs.xml excerpt

Comment: So, what's the result of a `Arrays.equals(x.getBytes(), y.getBytes())`?

Comment: this evaluates to true

Comment: Looks like it would be valid to use the Arrays.equals method - just out of interest because I never came across it before @spirit , is it that the encoding of each string is different that it's necessary to compare the bytes? Would the underscore in the string be causing the difference?

Comment: @KarenForde this method I've purpose only to eliminate situation where two strings are **look** the same, but **not** the same because of encodings.
Look at the correct answer, there is explanation of what happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With string comparison, always use .equals, since == will never (well, rarely unless you're comparing the same variable to itself) work for string, since they're immutable.

Edit:
So, I think it's because you don't have code within that block (or any code that matters). Add a print statement within that block and see if it prints. Compilers optimize out dead code, so it might be making you think something weird is happening when there really isn't. Feed the equals check into a boolean and see how it evaluates.

Comment: No, the key is the value of the key to retrieve the actual value from preferences.  So, when you're getting the value, it's the value that's mapped to that key's mapping.  They are likely not going to be equal unless you're storing Key -> Key mappings.

Comment: then surely the debugger would show this visually? I've seen plenty of examples where this works. If its not the case, what is the solution

Comment: Just to add, I am using `.equals()` the `==` is only shown to demonstrate that I have tried other solutions

Comment: From your debug log if you do x.equals(y) that should return true.  I'm not really sure what you're trying to do though, are you trying to get the stored preference value?  Because that's already passed to you in the method as a parameter.

Comment: I'm trying to check which preference was changed, so I can delegate logic accordingly

Comment: So, I think it's because you don't have code within that block (or any code that matters).  Add a print statement within that block and see if it prints.  Compilers optimize out dead code, so it might be making you think something weird is happening when there really isn't.  Feed the equals check into a boolean and see how it evaluates.

Comment: the debugger won't step in to the block, regardless of the block contents as the evaluation is false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116143/discussion-between-submersed-and-mcgowan-b).